# How to downgrade from Fedora 31 to Fedora 30

Tags: fedora

Is there a way to rollback to an older Fedora version from current version without reinstalling the OS?

If yes I'd like to know how to do it, specifically from Fedora 31 to Fedora 30, if no, then that's also fine, will just have to do it manually again. Just want to know so that I don't have to go through setting up everything again if there's simply a way to downgrade.

I don't suppose `sudo dnf system-upgrade download --releasever=30` will work since that was used from Fedora 29 to Fedora 30.

Comment: Downgrades are not supported and that version is already EOL.

Comment: I see, thanks for clarifying that. I might even switch to a different OS. Still not sure, all I use this laptop for is programming.

Comment: @jordanm Fedora 30 EOL is [June 3, 2020](https://fedorapeople.org/groups/schedule/f-30/f-30-all-tasks.html), which is still in the future from my timezone ;-).

Comment: @Manu perhaps if you explain the problem you’re trying to solve (by downgrading), you could get a better answer...

Comment: @StephenKitt One of my main concerns was [not being able to use OBS](https://obsproject.com/forum/threads/fedora-31-preview-window-is-transparent.112877/)  anymore and some snap issues. But that's fine, as I was going to revert to an older version anyways. Just wanted to make sure there was no "easy" way to do it that I was missing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is yes. Here's the exact syntax:

```
dnf install system-upgrade --releasever=31 --allowerasing
```

Note - this was from 32 to 31.

The long answer is as follows.

It grabs 300+ odd packages:

```
(345/345): mutter328-libs-3.28.4-4.fc31.x86_64.rpm   3.5 MB/s | 2.0 MB     00:00
```

If you have a gpg key, it will ask for permission to import it:

```
Importing GPG key 0x3C3359C4:
 Userid     : "Fedora (31) <fedora-31-primary@fedoraproject.org>"
 Fingerprint: 7D22 D586 7F2A 4236 474B F7B8 50CB 390B 3C33 59C4
 From       : /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-fedora-31-x86_64
Is this ok [y/N]: y
```

Once it has downloaded all the packages, it runs 600+ checks:

```
Verifying        : libtracker-control-2.3.4-1.fc32.x86_64                  684/687
Verifying        : libtracker-miner-2.3.4-1.fc32.x86_64                    685/687
Verifying        : python3-dasbus-0.2-2.fc32.noarch                        686/687
Verifying        : python3-nftables-1:0.9.3-3.fc32.x86_64                  687/687
```

Finally it displays the summary of changes:

```
Downgraded:
  abrt-2.14.2-2.fc31.x86_64
  abrt-addon-ccpp-2.14.2-2.fc31.x86_64
  abrt-addon-kerneloops-2.14.2-2.fc31.x86_64
  abrt-addon-pstoreoops-2.14.2-2.fc31.x86_64
...
  xdg-desktop-portal-gtk-1.4.0-1.fc31.x86_64
  yum-4.2.21-1.fc31.noarch

Installed:
  libreoffice-draw-1:6.3.6.2-3.fc31.x86_64
  mutter328-libs-3.28.4-4.fc31.x86_64
  python-unversioned-command-3.7.7-1.fc31.noarch
  python3-asn1crypto-0.24.0-7.fc31.noarch
  python3-dnf-plugin-system-upgrade-4.0.10-1.fc31.noarch
  python3-dnf-plugins-extras-common-4.0.10-1.fc31.noarch
  python3-pydbus-0.6.0-9.fc31.noarch

Removed:
  libtracker-control-2.3.4-1.fc32.x86_64    libtracker-miner-2.3.4-1.fc32.x86_64
  python3-dasbus-0.2-2.fc32.noarch          python3-nftables-1:0.9.3-3.fc32.x86_64
```

One thing it does not do is change the release notification

```
2020-06-18 09:36:34 localhost:/tmp #cat /etc/redhat-release
Fedora release 32 (Thirty Two)
2020-06-18 09:38:21 localhost:/tmp #cat /etc/fedora-release
Fedora release 32 (Thirty Two)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo dnf system-upgrade download --releasever=30
```

has worked for me to downgrade from Fedora 31 back to a working Fedora 30 system (my proxy server for Docker has issues starting Docker) using Fedora server (in a VM).

I also had to downgrade my Fedora 31 Laptop back to 30 due to font rendering issues which made everything except terminal unreadable.

No issues whatsoever.