# Rolling back from fedora 40 to 39

Tags: fedora

I installed the fedora 40 beta, and (as expected) it broke some extensions, so I'd like to know if there's a way to roll back to 39 without reinstalling the os. I tried with `sudo dnf install system-upgrade --releasever=39 --allowerasing` as in [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/564600/how-to-downgrade-from-fedora-31-to-fedora-30) question,
but it didn't work, it gives the following error: `No match for argument: system-upgrade Error: Unable to find a match: system-upgrade`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Downgrading a major release of Fedora has been done as you can see from the question that you referenced but it isn't supported and isn't guaranteed to work. In some cases, it just makes things worse.

Your best option in this case is to back up any needed data and then reinstall Fedora 39 and then wait until the official release of Fedora 40 comes out on April 16th and then update to that or better yet, create a Fedora 40 virtual machine to make sure that what you need is functional and then upgrade to it. The reason that you are having issues is most likely because you upgraded to a beta release where there are things that still haven't been finalized.

Comment: yeah, I thought so... the stuff that doesn't work isn't too important for me so I guess I'll just wait for updates. thank you for answering!